# Extracting Predictive Words from Android Keyboard Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, keyboard, indic

I use a keyboard app which suggests correct spelling of most of the Bangla words. Is there any way to extract this dictionary file as some sort of text file, so that I can use it on windows for Bangla spell checking?

Comment: Awesome question.. I was asking myself the same thing. If we could get at the lexicon / training data could we use it in another environment?